# Find string pattern then paste a 0 onto end of the string

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to find a pattern of four numbers, a full stop and a single digit, then add a zero onto the end of that string if found amongst strings like the below.

Example (small subset)

```
x <- c("5055.1","5055.10.10","5055.10.10.10","5065.1","5065.10.10","5065.10.10.10")
```

I want to add a zero to the two values that end in '1' so that they end in '10' as this is how the actual string should look, ie. 5055.10 or 5065.10.

I can find the string with the below;

```
grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d{1}$',x)
```

but I cannot work out how to add the '0' to the end of the string if it matches that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Other options could be using `sub` with `perl=T` and `\K` to forget what is matched so far. In the replacement append a zero.

```
x <- c("5055.1","5055.10.10","5055.10.10.10","5065.1","5065.10.10","5065.10.10.10")
sub('^\\d{4}\\.\\d\\K$', "0",x, perl=T)
```

Output

```
[1] "5055.10"       "5055.10.10"    "5055.10.10.10" "5065.10"      
[5] "5065.10.10"    "5065.10.10.10"
```

Or using a capture group:

```
sub('^(\\d{4}\\.\\d)$', "\\10",x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```r
sub("$", "0", grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d$', x, value=TRUE))
```

With `grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d$', x, value=TRUE)`, you extract the matching strings and then replacing `$` (end of string) with `0` adds `0` to those strings.

Without regex:

```r
paste0(grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d$', x,  value=TRUE), "0")
```

See an online [R demo](https://ideone.com/e5zfdt):

```r
x <- c("5055.1","5055.10.10","5055.10.10.10","5065.1","5065.10.10","5065.10.10.10")
sub("$", "0", grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d$',x, value=TRUE))
# => [1] "5055.10" "5065.10"
paste0(grep('^\\d{4}\\.\\d$', x,  value=TRUE), "0")
# => [1] "5055.10" "5065.10"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor - I knew there would be a simple solution. Perhaps I have been looking at this for too long. Your solution works perfectly.